# If $\langle A,B \rangle=0$ for two symmetric matrices, what about $\langle A,B^{-1}\rangle $?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, orthogonality, trace

You are given two square real symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$. They are mutually orthogonal $A \perp B$, or in other words their frobenius inner product is zero, or in other words $\langle A ,\, B\rangle_F=0$.

My intuition says $A\perp B^{-1}$, i.e. $\langle A, B^{-1}\rangle_F=0$, but I don't really know how to approach proving such an expression. Can you prove or disprove such a claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$. Then $\langle A, B\rangle = 0$ but $\langle A, B^{-1}\rangle = \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Touche! I now realize i forgot to write one more important addition: they are positive semidefinite... Should I add a new question or edit the existing one?

Comment: Your answer is perfect to the question as asked, so I'd be happy to accept it if I'm to write a new question.

Comment: @LudvigH If $A$ is PSD and $B$ is positive definite, their inner product is zero only if $A=0$. Hence $A$ is obviously orthogonal to $B^{-1}$.

Comment: With that, i skip the second question, and accept the given answer!